# jQuery add input elements to the correct <td>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to achieve the result of image below. 
[image]

As you can see the `inputs` (the boxes in the middle) are only insered where they belong to the specific `color_id` and `size_id`.

I'm currently retrieving the results by AJAX and I want to dynamically add input elements to the right `<td>`. This means that there are some `<td>` which won't be filled (with `input`, but must be filled as empty).

Since this is not a server side problem although I retrieve the information from it, I created a **[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/snjvo0wL/)** so you guys can see.

My problem here is how am I going to, dynamically, match the color with the size column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here take a look at this code:

```
$(function () {
    var head = ''; // holds thead <th>
    var line = ''; // holds tbody <tr>

    var sizes = ['21', '22', 'M'];

    var colors = [{
        'id': 1,
            'name': 'Blue'
    }, {
        'id': 2,
            'name': 'Yellow'
    }, {
        'id': 3,
            'name': 'Red'
    }];

    var inputs = [{
        'color_id': '1',
            'size': '21'
    }, {
        'color_id': '1',
            'size': '22'
    }, {
        'color_id': '2',
            'size': '22'
    }, {
        'color_id': '2',
            'size': 'M'
    }, {
        'color_id': '3',
            'size': '21'
    }, {
        'color_id': '3',
            'size': 'M'
    }];

    head += '<tr>';
    head += '   <th></th>';

    for (var i = 0; i < sizes.length; i++)
    head += '<th>' + sizes[i] + '</th>';

    head += '</tr>';

    for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
        line += '<tr>';
        line += '   <td>' + colors[i].name + '</td>';

        for (var y = 0; y < sizes.length; y++) {
            var testObj = {
                'color_id': colors[i].id.toString(),
                    'size': sizes[y]
            }
            var hasInput = false;
            for (var j = 0; j < inputs.length; j++) {
                hasInput = inputs[j]['color_id'] == testObj['color_id'] && inputs[j]['size'] == testObj['size'];
                if (hasInput) break;


            }

            if (hasInput) {
                line += '<td><input type="text"/></td>';

            } else {
                line += '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
            }
        }

        line += '</tr>';
    }

    $('#myTable thead').append(head);
    $('#myTable tbody').append(line);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working. Now I'm going to lose some time understanding your logic/algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

You got the basic structure right, but your inner `for` loop logic isn't right. You want to add a text input, if the `size` attribute of the `inputs` object is equal to the `size` in the current `td` you are looking at, not equal to the `color`. If it is not equal you need to add an empty table cell. Since your `input` object does not contain information about empty data cells, you need to add a counter for the element id you want to insert next:

```
var element = 0;
for(var i = 0; i <= colors.length - 1; i++)
{
   line += '<tr>';
   line += '   <td>' + colors[i].name + '</td>';

   for (var y = 0; y <= sizes.length - 1; y++) {
       if (inputs[element] && inputs[element].color_id == i+1 && inputs[element].size == sizes[y]) {
            line += '<td><input type="text"/></td>';
            element++;
        } else line += '<td></td>';
    }

   line += '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: I took so long to answer you because I've been testing. I was going to accept your answer but it wasn't working on my side (although I tested on JSFiddle..). So, I've came to conclusion that this doesn't work always. I've put a real example on JSfiddle (like I have on my project) and you can check it. http://jsfiddle.net/snjvo0wL/10/

Comment: @Linesofcode I'm sorry, I ignored some special cases there (was too hasty). It should work now. Notice that I picked up on your colors being 1-based in the if-statement. If you change that, you have to change the if-statement too

Comment: Yes, now works. Since I've accepted the other answer, I have upvoted your post. Thank you.